# Core data fetch request optimization with segment control

Tags: iphone, ios, optimization, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment control with 5 items, on selecting every item data is filter on some criteria and a different result is displayed. All the five choices in segment control use the same entity to fetch the data.

Currently i have a fetchresultcontroller and whenever there is a value change in the segment control i fetch data from the same entity with a different predicate and reload the table with new data.

I am looking to optimize this. Am I doing it the right way or what is the right way to do it?

Also what is the best way to change the sorting order between ascending and descending for an already fetched data.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post some code snippets?

If you already fetched a set of MangedObjcts you can reorder the NSArray with a Sort Descirptor: [sortedArrayUsingDescriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingDescriptors%3a)

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only fetching a small number of NSManagedObjects, there probably isn't much optimization to be done. CoreData and its corresponding classes (such as the FetchResultsController you are using, which is designed to work particularly well with UITableViews) do most of the heavy lifting for you.

In terms of the best way to change the sorting order between ascending and descending; this is determined in something like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"someEntityProperty" ascending:YES/NO];
```

If you set ascending to YES, you'll get your NSManagedObjects back sorted smallest to largest ascending) on the key you provide. If you set it to NO, you'll get them back largest to smallest (descending).